# Apartment number / Unit number returned from google places api

Tags: ios, google-places-api

Hello I was just wondering if there was any way to return the unit number of an address with the google places api. (Ex.. Unit 15, 123 Fake St. or #15, 123 Fake st. or 15-123 Fake St. or 15/123 Fake St. etc...). Here is example code from googles website that i am attempting to use. I currently have the code working to the point that it will return an address, but I am unable to add any unit/suite number onto it. Thanks for the help.

```
import UIKit
import GooglePlaces

class ViewController: UIViewController {

  var resultsViewController: GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController?
  var searchController: UISearchController?
  var resultView: UITextView?

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    resultsViewController = GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController()
    resultsViewController?.delegate = self

    searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: resultsViewController)
    searchController?.searchResultsUpdater = resultsViewController

    let subView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 65.0, width: 350.0, height: 45.0))

    subView.addSubview((searchController?.searchBar)!)
    view.addSubview(subView)
    searchController?.searchBar.sizeToFit()
    searchController?.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false

    // When UISearchController presents the results view, present it in
    // this view controller, not one further up the chain.
    definesPresentationContext = true
  }
}

// Handle the user's selection.
extension ViewController: GMSAutocompleteResultsViewControllerDelegate {
  func resultsController(_ resultsController: GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController,
                         didAutocompleteWith place: GMSPlace) {
    searchController?.isActive = false
    // Do something with the selected place.
    print("Place name: \(place.name)")
    print("Place address: \(place.formattedAddress)")
    print("Place attributions: \(place.attributions)")
  }

  func resultsController(_ resultsController: GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController,
                         didFailAutocompleteWithError error: Error){
    // TODO: handle the error.
    print("Error: ", error.localizedDescription)
  }

  // Turn the network activity indicator on and off again.
  func didRequestAutocompletePredictions(forResultsController resultsController: GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController) {
    UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
  }

  func didUpdateAutocompletePredictions(forResultsController resultsController: GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController) {
    UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
  }
}
```

Comment: I believe that's not yet possible.

Comment: Still doesn't seem to be possible. Seems very risky to use it without apartment when someone is entering a mailing address :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving my issue by switching to a different api for autocompletion. I am now using https://developer.here.com/